# How to measure height and width of object using camera?

Tags: java, android

I referred lot many links but still I am not able to get any point from that I can start my development. I want to measure my image height and width using camera. I found this app . I want to make this type of application not exactly same but quite same but for my requirement I want to measure my image height and width  using camera.

I want to measure school bag height and width.

Can anyone give me/suggest me the right way or any simple example code so that I can get more idea about this requirement.

Comment: _Questions asking us to **recommend or find** a book, tool, software library, **tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow_ - You need to do some in depth research.

Comment: Manar, you might want to start at looking the basics required for measuring using a camera. One of the common things I've seen between some solutions is the reference.
For example a small piece of paper, QR code, etc. That can help you set up a scale and go from there based on proportions. I don't think you can simply "measure" something without that.

Comment: Florin,Thank you I'm going to learn this part

Comment: basically to measure the size of any item, you have to know the distance to that item, so you can calculate it's real size. You won't be able to do something without knowing the distance

Answer (score -2, accepted):

#### I am answering this in context of:

> I want to make this type of application not exactly same but quite same but for my requirement I want to measure my image height and width using camera.

You can get height and width of ImageView by using `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` through while this will not give you the exact width and height of the image, for getting the Image width height first you need to get the drawable as background then convert drawable to `BitmapDrawable` to get the image as `Bitmap` from that you can get the width and height like here

```
Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getBackground()).getBitmap();
int w = b.getWidth();
int h = b.getHeight();
```

or do like here

```
imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap b = imageView.getDrawingCache();
int w = b.getWidth();
int h = b.getHeight();
```

the above code will give you current imageview sized bitmap like screen shot of device

for only ImageView size

```
imageView.getWidth(); 
imageView.getHeight();
```

If you have drawable image and you want that size you can get like this way

```
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.yourimage);
int h = d.getIntrinsicHeight(); 
int w = d.getIntrinsicWidth();
```

---

```
╔═══════════════════════════════╗   ^
║ ImageView    ╔══════════════╗ ║   |
║              ║              ║ ║   |
║              ║ Actual image ║ ║   |
║              ║              ║ ║   |60px height of ImageView
║              ║              ║ ║   |
║              ║              ║ ║   |
║              ╚══════════════╝ ║   |
╚═══════════════════════════════╝   v
<------------------------------->
                   90px width of ImageView
```

Comment: Beautiful. But how does this post answer the question "How do I measure an **object** size"?

Comment: OK, and how do you measure a book, a glass, a pencil, ... with your method? I don't think the OP wants to know how many **pixels** is an image of a shoe.

Comment: Measuring the size of an image is not the same as measuring the size of the _object_ shown in the image, so this really doesn't answer the question.